# Visual Studio Android Emulator does not appear in debug emulator list

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova, vs-android

I'm using visual studio 2015 update 2 and Tools For Apache Cordova Update 10.
I installed Visual Studio Android Emulator with Ms Installer but after installation it does not appears in debug emulators for android (and other platforms).

[image: vs emulator for android is absent in the emulators list]

- the project run in Ripple correctly
- the vs emulator will start and run correctly , 3 virtual machines start correctly with no problem. (Tools > Visual Studio Emulator For Android)
  but i can't see the VS Emulator for debugging in the list for my apache cordova project

Answer (score 0):

The Emulators are based on Hyper-V, so the feature is not available all the time. If you use a 32Bit Windows or an 64Bit Windows, but the CPU misses VT-X, SLAT support you also can't use Hyper-V. Also Hyper-V is only part of the Pro or Enterprise edition, if you only use the Home Edition you're out of luck and have to upgrade to Pro.

If you support all requirements, try to repair the Visual Studio 2015 and also update to Update 3.

Comment: I stated that the emulator installed and started normally , but does not appear in debug list . this means my pc fully support the emulator requirments

Comment: uninstalling and installing VS 2015 with update 3 solved the problem !